# What are the things to look for in a contact for a software developer working remotely

Tags: software-industry, contractors, contracting

I *may* have an opportunity to work remotely from different country for my current employer. If they do offer me a contract what would be the main points (gotchas) to look for in there from a position of a software developer?

For example meaning:

- Minimum amount of hours per week.
- Letting you know in advance before terminating the contract.

Are there any other things to keep in mind that may make my life easier?

Comment: Is this your home country or is it a foreign posting?

Comment: The company is located in New Zealand, my country is in Europe.

Comment: But this is "you get to work from your home country" not "you are going and working in a random other foreign country for your employer" right? Those are very different use cases.

Comment: I get to work from my home country.

Comment: I don't understand how this can be closed as opinion-based; there are specific things to look for in contracts such as hours of work, termination criteria, etc.

Comment: @omouse I don't understand it either. It's another stackexchange wanna-be administrator's closure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Things to make sure are covered:

- Payment terms; consequences of late or non-payment
- Assignment of rights (i.e. they do not get the rights until AFTER final payment has been received)
- Termination (by them or you): how is unpaid balance/unfinished work handled?

I would also delineate methods and frequency of communication (from both parties), revisions, code reviews, schedules, status, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should wear the shoes of the employer as well as yourself. As an employer who has employed people overseas, I ask for:

Minimum hours
3 weeks advance notice of days off
A daily work report
No requirement to pay benefits (special instance)
Two weeks advance notice (keeping a bonus pool available that gets cancelled if this is not achieved)

If I were the contractor:
Defined minimum hours
Performance review intervals
Advance notice of termination (one month)
Internet access reimbursement
Travel reimbursement